# Change columns order in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change columns order of my page layout. Here I use `bootstrap` and tried with .col-sm-push-* and .col-sm-pull-* modifier classes. But I can't get it to work.

My HTML is something like this -

```
<section class="sidebar">
    .....
    .....
    .....
</section> <!-- /.sidebar -->

<section class="content">
    .....
    .....
    .....
</section> <!-- /.content -->


<section class="request">
    .....
    .....
    .....
</section> <!-- /.request -->
```

There are 3 columns and now I need to display them differently according to the screen sizes.

In small and higher screen size, I need to display them in a single row. like this,

```
[sidebar] [content] [request]
```

In extra small size, I need to change its order, like this

```
[content]
[request]
[sidebar]
```

This is how I tried it in my `Less` file. but its not working for me.

```
.sidebar {
    .make-sm-column(3);
    .make-sm-column-pull(3)

    .....
}   

.content {
    .make-sm-column(5);
    .make-sm-column-push(5)

    .....
}   

.request {
    .make-sm-column(4);
    .make-sm-column-pull(4)

    .....
}
```

Hope someone may help me regarding this. 
Thank you.

Comment: .pull-right will do the trick...

Comment: you mean, pull-right class?

Comment: yes, try it, but I'm confuse that newer version has or not... just check it...

Comment: @C-linkNepal, I am not sure how to use that classes to change columns order of the layout...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 is a **mobile first** framework. Therefore you should change your HTML structure to your desired mobile structure first. Like this for example:

```
<section class="content">
    .....
</section> <!-- /.content -->

<section class="request">
    .....
</section> <!-- /.request -->

<section class="sidebar">
    .....
</section> <!-- /.sidebar -->
```

Next you should add the pull and push assignments, like you already tried to do. But you got the logic wrong, you need to pull / push the elements according to the other elements that should be "jumped".

I don't know about the `LESS` syntax, but with `CSS` classes you markup would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
<section class="content col-md-5 col-sm-push-4">
    Content
</section> <!-- /.content -->

<section class="request col-md-4 col-sm-push-3">
    Requests
</section> <!-- /.request -->

<section class="sidebar col-md-3 col-sm-pull-9">
    Sidebar
</section> <!-- /.sidebar -->
</div>
```

Maybe in `LESS` it would be like this:

```
.sidebar {
    .make-sm-column(3);
    .make-sm-column-pull(9)

.....
}   

.content {
    .make-sm-column(5);
    .make-sm-column-push(4)

    .....
}   

.request {
    .make-sm-column(4);
    .make-sm-column-push(3)

    .....
}
```

But remember to change your HTML structure first!

[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/bnrA7jbwyI)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can you explain a little the logic behind this

Comment: In you example `Sidebar` is the LAST col and has a col-5 and a col-4 before it. Now you want to make it the FIRST col, you therefore have to PULL it 9 (5 + 4) cols. `Content` on the other hand is the FIRST col and should move to the second, which has a col-4. Therefore it has to be PUSHED by 4. I hope you understand where I'm getting at..

Comment: Maybe try playing a bit with the bootply I created until you get the concept. Once you understood it, it's really easy.. ;)

Comment: confuse thing is how to use `pull` and `push` classes and its number.

Comment: Use `push` to move things 'forward' and `pull` to move things 'backward'. And the number is the col numbers to be 'skipped', like col-5 + col-4 = 'skip' 9.

Comment: Thanks.. I understood. content class should be change to `.make-sm-column-push(3)` isn't it?

Comment: As I said I don't know about the `LESS` syntax, but the number in the classes should always be the number of the original col of the element where it should move to. Always dependent of the breakpoints (eg. md, lg, sm,..) of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and clear explanation. got it very well. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Mybe you can try this:

```
<!-- Columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop -->
<div class="row">
    <section class="sidebar col-xs-6 col-md-4">Sidebar</section>

    <section class="content col-xs-6 col-md-4">Content</section>

    <section class="request col-xs-6 col-md-4">request</section>
</div>
```

you can find more here : [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

For column resets use a combination of a `.clearfix` and responsive utility class `.visible-xs-block`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section class="col-xs-4 col-sm-push-4">Content</section>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        <section class="col-xs-4 col-sm-push-4">Request</section>
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
        <section class="col-xs-4 col-sm-pull-8">Sidebar</section>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example in [Codepen](http://codepen.io/neilhem/pen/xitda)